# Assigning mass property to collision objects in MoveIt

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I just want to confirm if there is a way to assign mass property to collision objects in MoveIt?

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/385365/assigning-mass-property-to-collision-objects-in-moveit/) by [k2108](https://answers.ros.org/users/30550/k2108/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2021-08-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No. There isn't.

To avoid an [xy-problem](https://xyproblem.info): what is it you're actually trying to do / solve?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-08-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [k2108](https://answers.ros.org/users/30550/k2108/) on 2021-08-30**:
Thank you for your answer and apologies for not including the complete task in the question. I am trying to create a scene with objects of different weights and use a robotic arm (panda) to pick from one location and place it to another site. The objective is to find the energy/power consumed by the robot in various pick and place movements of weighted objects.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-08-30**:\

> The objective is to find the energy/power consumed by the robot in various pick and place movements of weighted objects.

MoveIt's default planners do not take dynamics into account, so they will not create different plans with "different payloads".

For simulating dynamics you'd perhaps be better off with using an actual dynamics simulator, such as Gazebo or Webots.